# please help me with a menu in C(terminal) cause my professor can't

Tags: c

I'm a computer science student (first year, and barely done programming) and while studying  **switch statements** in the laboratory our professor wrote this code that doesn't work(he really thought it gonna work).... and just stared at this for a lot of time.
In any case you need to know:
Citire means read
Afisare means show
Suma means sum
Cauta means search
Dati valoarea de cautat = what value to find;
Operatie necorespunzatoare = improper operation;

Can someone explain why it doesn't work? I tried to make it without functions but it's still not working. I really want to know why!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int n, v[10];
void citire(int *n,int v[10]){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
}
void afisare(int *n,int v[10])
{
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int suma(int n, int v[10])
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum=sum+v[i];
    return sum;
}
int cauta(int n, int v[10])
{
    int x;
    printf("dati valoarea de cautat");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(v[i]==x)
    return i;
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    char c;
    do{
            system("cls");
    printf("\nC. citire sir de numere\nA. afisare sir\nS. afisare suma\nF. cautare element in vector\nI. info autor\nX. Iesire\n");
    switch(c = getch())
    {
    case 'c':
        citire(n,v);
        getch();
        break;
    case 'a':
        afisare(n,v);
        getch();
        break;
    case 's':
        printf("%d",suma(n,v));
        getch();
        break;
    case 'f':
        printf("%d",cauta(n,v));
        getch();
        break;
    case 'x':
        exit(0);
    default:
        printf("\noperatie necorespunzatoare");

    }
    }while(c!='x');

    return 0;
```

Comment: What this code is supposed to do? Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is this program supposed to do? Can you be a bit more explicit about "not working"? Compilation, runtime error, logical error...? Thanks.

Comment: There is a whole bunch of problem in this code indeed. The professor seem not to have invested much time in it.

Comment: `void afisare(int *n,int v[10])` --> `void afisare(int n,int v[10])`

Comment: My fault, sorry! with option C you insert a string, with A to show it, with S to show the sum, with F to search an element from the string and show you, I is irelevant, and X to close the app :) sorry again for not providing enough info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here

```
void citire(int *n,int v[10]){  <--- expects pointer to int
    scanf("%d", &n);            <--- wrong, n is already a pointer
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)        <--- wrong, n is a pointer. Not an int
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
}
```

and it is called like:

```
citire(n,v);   <--- wrong. passing int but function expects pointer
```

The correct call is

```
citire(&n,v);   // Pass pointer
```

and the function should rather be:

```
void citire(int *n,int v[10]){
    if (scanf("%d", n) != 1) exit(1);
    for(int i=0; i< *n; i++)
        if (scanf("%d", &v[i]) != 1) exit(1);
}
```

Further:

```
void afisare(int *n,int v[10])  <-- wrong, you don't want a pointer here
```

Besides that it's real bad to put `int n, v[10];` as global variables. They should be put in `main`

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me! and sorry again for not providing enough info from the start!